# Long variable to char array

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Im very new to C++, I want to convert a *Long* variable to a *char* array and then print each one.

I need the conversion to use it on this function `modem.write(c);`
The c variable is char. And the variable i have is `long GMT = now.unixtime();`

So i suppose I need firts to convert *GMT* to an array of char and then call `modem.write` inside a for cycle?

EDIT0:

After a discussion with H2CO3 he explains me that modem.write is actually expecting a uint8_t and the vales needs to be ASCII code, so a more elaborated process should occur before sending the data.

EDIT1:

```
while(Serial.available()){
  char c = Serial.read();
  modem.write(c);
}

long GMT = now.unixtime();
char* newCode = totp.getCode(GMT);
```

EDIT 2:

```
char* buf;
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%ld", GMT);
modem.write(buf);
```

*error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'uint8_t'*

Comment: Since `char` is a special type regarding the strict aliasing rule, you can just grab a pointer to the first byte of the long and use the `const uint8_t *, size_t` overload of `SoftModem::write` like this: `modem.write((uint8_t *)&GMT, sizeof GMT);`

Comment: @H2CO3 you should post this as answer - I don't know much about arduino, so I just posted a generic answer for plain C, but yours seems to be better, so post it as answer so the OP can accept it!

Comment: Imagine `long GMT = now.unixtime(); = 1381592452` (date of the day), do you need to `modem.write()` the string `"1381592452"`or the value as the number `1381592452`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know that much about any arduino SDK, so this is just a possible very generic way of doing it in plain C under all the assumptions I could make from your question. There's probably a better way using some kind of arduino SDK.

Also, as has been pointed out, modem.write does either take a char, or a byte array and a size_t parameter, so I'm leaving this answer here for people to learn something which doesn't necessarily provide the best answer for this question, but still is correct in it's own (under the stated assumptions)

---

Assuming modem.write(...) really takes a `\0` terminated char array, and not a c++ string, this would be a possible way to do it in c:

```
char *c = malloc(sizeof(long) + 1);

if (!c) {
  // handle ENOMEM
}

strncpy(c, (const char *)&GMT, 4);

c[sizeof(long)] = '\0';
```

Comment: `write()` does not take a 0-terminated C string (nor do I see why you would assume that -- OP's writing binary data). It either takes a byte or an array of bytes along with a size.

Comment: I assumed it because the OP said "char array", and with single argument functions taking "char arrays" it's common in C that they are 0 terminated.

Comment: Yes, that's reasonable, but read the rest of the requirements. He wants to write a `long` as an array of bytes. It's not a 0-terminated C string, just a raw byte array.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes I got that (and just fixed my code, as it would've done a sigsegv before ...), that's why I'm showing how to copy a long into a char array and terminating it with '\0'. I'll update the answer to state that yours is probably the better way to do it, and leave mine as a generic C one (which only applies to a fictional modem.write() it seems ...)

Comment: @H2CO3 fine this way?

Comment: Sure it is. [15 chars]

Answer (score 2):

So on request (and if my assumption is correct...):

Since `char` is a special type regarding the strict aliasing rule, you can just grab a pointer to the first byte of the `long` and use the `const uint8_t *, size_t` overload of `SoftModem::write` like this:

```
modem.write((const uint8_t *)&GMT, sizeof GMT);
```

If you want to send a formatted, decimal **string,** then you have to convert your number accordingly first:

```
char buf[0x100];
int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%ld", GMT);
if (n > 0) {
    modem.write((const uint8_t *)buf, n)
}
```

<sub>(This works because AVR-libc, which the Arduino libraries are based on, typedefs `uint8_t` to `unsigned char`, [as seen here](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/avr-libc/include/stdint.h?root=avr-libc&view=markup). If `uint8_t` wasn't a (signed or unsigned) character type, then this would violate the strict aliasing rule.)</sub>

Comment: A somewhat dangerous assumption that `uint8_t` is an alias for a char type?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, but on the AVR platform it always is ([see here](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/trunk/avr-libc/include/stdint.h?root=avr-libc&view=markup)). But you're right, I've added a notice regarding this issue.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the problem with aliasing in this case? Shouldn't it be okay anyway as long as the function only takes one pointer argument and not multiple, which could alias each other (like strcpy)?

Comment: I cant get it to work right, i used the code you suggested but is not working, please check the edit I made, maybe it tells you something. The first part is the original code intended as you see for reading from the serial port, the next two lines are the variables i wish to send

Comment: @griffin The problem is that unless you alias through a character type, accessing an object using a pointer of a different base type is undefined behavior.

Comment: @DomingoSL No, your edit doesn't help much. It's still unclear what you're doing. Don't you need to send out the `long` byte by byte to the port?

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, but how is your code sending each byte if is not inside a cycle?

Comment: @DomingoSL It is calling the appropriate overload of `write()` that sends an entire array. Why do you think that method takes a `size` argument?

Comment: It does not seems to work, i mean, your code is ok, but seems that modem.write() is expecting an ascii code, so maybe we are doing the wrong codification, since the number 123 cant be send as 1 2 3 but 49 50 51 (their ASCII equivalent )

Comment: @DomingoSL My code does work. If you can't phrase your question correctly, that's not my fault. You didn't state you needed a textual, decimal representation of your number (that's a quite uncommon way to transfer data). If you need that, consider printing it to an array of `char`s using `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%ld", the_long);`, then send that array. But really, this is getting tiring. Read a basic C tutorial and think about your requirements before unjustly criticizing others.

Comment: I told you, your code IS OK, im only trying to figuring out how modem.writes works! If I knew C or how that function sends the information i wouldn't ask here in the first place, since i don't get it so well.

Comment: @DomingoSL Just as I said: use `snprintf()` and send the resulting buffer to the port as described in the answer.

Comment: @DomingoSL The compiler told you exactly what the problem was. `write` expects an `uint8_t *` and `uint8_t` is an `unsigned char`, but you are passing it an array of `char`. In this particular case, you can fix that using a simple typecast, but the code has another problem: `buf` is an uninitialized pointer. It doesn't point to anywhere, you rather want to allocate memory for that. But again, this has nothing to do with Arduino -- you are supposed to know C at least at a basic level before doing embedded programming. I suggest you read a good beginner C tutorial.

Comment: So you dont know how to fix this?

Comment: @DomingoSL I do know -- I have just explained it *twice.*

Comment: Can you please elaborate it on your answer so i can get it and in the future it could serve as a valid place to solve the problem without having to read all our discussion?

Comment: Edit0 made. Please take a look.

Comment: @DomingoSL I've updated my answer with complete code, but **please don't copy-paste it** without understanding what it does and how. You may need to consult the documentation of `snprintf()`.